# Measuring for storm door on porch?

Tags: porch, storm-door

I'm replacing a storm door on our front porch. This is the only door on the porch as the exterior door to the house is inside the porch. I'm having trouble measuring...or rather knowing if my measurements are correct as using the measuring guides on [Home Depot](https://awwebcdnprdcd.azureedge.net/-/media/stormdoors/files/andersen-emco-storm-door-measure-guide.pdf?modified=20180605193757). I feel don't really relate to my scenario.

[image: Home Depot Measuring Guidelines]

I don't have exterior trim/brickmold (from what I can tell) on my porch. There is a door frame/jam leading into the porch, but there no exterior door. If I measure the width of the jam it's 30" and from the sill to the top of the frame is 79."

Obviously there are standard size doors of 30"x80" and these have about a 1" leeway for the rough space.

So my question(s) is am I measuring correctly and my dimensions are 30"x79" which will require a custom door, or will a standard 30"x80" door work since I don't have a way to really measure the brickmold as it doesn't exist?

I thought about just measuring the door that I am replacing or finding the model # to research online. It's an old Cole Sewell door though and I cannot find a model # anywhere.

***Edit: Here are some pictures of the actual porch/door. Note if I measure the outside frame of the current storm door it is 32"x80" which is a pretty standard size.***

[image: front porch storm door w dimensions]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: A picture of the porch would help.  I suspect that if a standard door doesn't fit, modifying the frame would be faster and cheaper than getting a custom-made storm door.

Comment: A standard storm door for a  32"x80"  should work.  ( or even a 34"x80" )You may need to ad some trim for mounting purposes. The storm door does not mount inside the opening so it can be a little bigger. As long as the storm door frame is bigger than the rough opening you are ok.

Comment: I added some images above of the current storm door and porch.